# JavaScript split string by comma and character count

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, split

I have a string that contains about 10,000 ids comma separated and I would like to split them by commas plus make sure that the character count in each one of them doesn't exceed 1500 characters.

For E.g.:

```
var str = "12345, 567789, 435345, 55446444564, 786756, 33322 .... ";
var commaSeperatedSplitArr = str.split(",");
var arrayOfArrays = [];
var limit = 50;

// So, I would like to get my commaSeperatedSplitArr[0].length >= 1500 and <= 1600 characters such that none of the Ids are cropped off    
while(commaSeperatedSplitArr.length > 0) {
    var splicedCharCount = arrayOfEmails.splice(0, limit)[0].length;
    if(splicedCharCount >= 1500 && splicedCharCount <= 1600) {
        arrayOfArrays.push(commaSeperatedSplitArr.splice(0, limit));  
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? I have tried using str.splice(0, limit) but that just gives me for the count of limit rather than the number of characters I want.

**Update:**

Also, how can we use the above approach to apply for a list of email addresses?

```
For E.g.: var str = "abc@gmail.com, xyz@help-desk.com, hello@world.com.... "
```

**Expected Result:**
1) For Ids: (if limit is 50 characters)

```
arrayOfArrays[0] = "12345, 567789, ... "; (should contain 50 characters or less without any id being cropped off.)
```

2) For Email Addresses: (if limit is 50 characters)

```
arrayofArrays[0] = "abc@gmail.com, xyz@help-desk.com,..."; (should contain 50 characters or less without any email address being cropped off.)
```

Looking forward to your solution guys.
Cheers.

Comment: So an id can have more than 1500 characters?

Comment: Not really, but its just the character count that I want to keep track of as I am trying to split it into an array of arrays.

Comment: What would you want to do if they exceed 1500, simply not add them to the array?

Comment: So you mean that you need it separated into arrays of ids, where each array holds no more than 1500 characters? And you don't want to cut off an id between arrays?

Comment: Yes but I am creating an array of arrays. Please see my updated code and I want arrayOfArrays[0].length to not be greater than 1600 and not less than 1500.

Comment: @AndrewMairose: Yes exactly. Sorry, if I wasn't explaining it well enough.

Comment: So you want 1500 ids per array or 1500 characters?

Comment: 1500 characters in arrayOfArrays[0] and same in arrayOfArrays[1] etc...

Comment: Lets say limit is 5 what is desired result for your `str`?

Comment: If the limit is 5 characters, then I'd just expect the first id to appear in arrayOfArrays[0]. i.e. arrayOfArrays[0] = "12345" but we wouldn't have arrayOfArrays[1] = 566789 (more than 5 characters).

Comment: @TheNewbie ok wait...Give us an example of the **result** you desire that pertains to the code you posted.

Comment: @zer00ne: Updated the question to specify the expected result.

Comment: @TheNewbie why a character count? Why not an element count? If an average email address: `average123@gmail.com` is 20 characters then at 50 characters it'll be an average of 2.5 email addresses to filter. What are you doing with groups of 2 to 3 email addresses?

Comment: I am basically using this character count for an sql query and make sure that the query length does not exceed 1500 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines:

```js
var str = "12345, 567789, 435345, 55446444564, 786756, 33322";
var commaSeparatedSplitArr = str.split(", ");
var arrayOfArrays = [];
var currentArrayCharCount = 0;
var currentArray = [];
var arrayCharCountLimit = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < commaSeparatedSplitArr.length; i++) {
  var currentId = commaSeparatedSplitArr[i];
  if (currentArrayCharCount + currentId.length > arrayCharCountLimit) {
    arrayOfArrays.push(currentArray);
    currentArray = [];
    currentArrayCharCount = 0;
    if (currentId.length <= arrayCharCountLimit) {
      currentArray.push(currentId);
      currentArrayCharCount += currentId.length;
    } else {
      console.error("ID: " + currentId + " is too long!");
    }
  } else {
    currentArray.push(currentId);
    currentArrayCharCount += currentId.length;
  }
}
arrayOfArrays.push(currentArray);
console.log(arrayOfArrays);
```

Also, you may want to consider changing your split character to `", "` (including the space) if there are in fact spaces in your string, so that the ids don't all contain a space at the beginning.

**EDIT:** Made some corrections and converted to a stack snippet.

Comment: Sorry @Andrew. This doesn't work and it just returns the same split array that I had from before.

Comment: Actually, if we don't use the splice(), your approach works well.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner solution using regexps.

It changes the last coma before the limit-th character of the string with a pipe, keeps doing that until the end of the string. then splits on the pipes.

```js
var str = "12345, 567789, 435345, 55446444564, 786756, 33322, 12345, 567789, 435345, 55446444564, 786756, 33322, 12345, 567789, 435345, 55446444564, 786756, 33322"
var limit = 20;

var regex = new RegExp(`([^]{1,${limit}})(, |$)`, "g");
var out = str.replace(regex, "|$1").slice(1).split("|")

console.log(out.map(l => `"${l}"\t\t(size: ${l.length})`).join("\n"))
```

### EDIT

here's the example without the template literals to support older browsers

```js
var str = "12345, 567789, 435345, 55446444564, 786756, 33322, 12345, 567789, 435345, 55446444564, 786756, 33322, 12345, 567789, 435345, 55446444564, 786756, 33322"
    var limit = 20;

    var regex = new RegExp('([^]{1,' + limit + '})(, |$)', "g");
    var out = str.replace(regex, "|$1").slice(1).split("|")

    console.log(out.map(l => '"'+l+'"\t\t(size: '+l.length+')').join("\n"))
```

Comment: IE doesn't accept ` as a valid character. How can we fix this?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example that should run in IE as it is

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I applied 1500 as my limit to the number of characters but it doesn't seem to take that into account... it still pushes everything into out[0].

Comment: what's the length of str?

Comment: I think you should clarify the question first, because the ids format shouldn't be a problem here. Give us a reasonable example of input and of expected output, then i'll be able to fix the answer

Comment: I've updated my question and added the extra complexity that I am facing.

Comment: I still don't see a reasonable example of input and output, like: "1, 2, 3" => ["1", "2", "3"]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134801/discussion-between-the-newbie-and-alebianco).